# PySpark: Problem building logic to read data from multiple format files

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am facing issue creating empty dataframe with a defined number of columns in a list. I'll try to explain the issue here.

I don't know how to create empty data frame and what is the best way to iterate each file with multiple formats and merge the data in a single data fame

```
list_of_columns = [a,b,c,d]

finalDF = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=list_of_columns)

for file in list_of_files:
    if format = '.csv':
        df1 = spark.read.csv(CSVFile)
        finalDF = df1.union(df1)
    elif format = '.parquet':
        df2 = spar.read.parque(ParquetFile)
        finalDF = df2.union(df2)

finalDF.show()
```

Comment: where is the `format` variable being defined? also, what are the issues being faced?

Comment: the format variable is defined from the file extension of s3 objects(object['Key'].split("/")[-1]

Comment: I am getting below error:
ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset